# Python code to open all files in a directory and print their first line

Tags: python, python-3.x

There are 2 ".XFR" files in a folder **abc** with plain text inside them.
Purpose is to write a script that opens each of the files and print their first line.
Tried the following code:

```
import os
import glob   

f = []
path = r"C:\Users\Ajay\Desktop\abc"
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(path):
    f.extend(filenames)
    break
print(f)

files=glob.glob(path)   
for file in files:     
    f=open(file, 'r')  
    f.readlines()
    print(f)    
    f.close()
```

It lists all the files correctly but for fileopen, it's giving me an error that says:

```
(base) C:\Users\Ajay\Desktop>python readline.py
['1234.XFR', '23465.XFR']
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "readline.py", line 14, in <module>
f=open(file, 'r')
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 
'C:\\Users\\Ajay\\Desktop\\abc'
```

[Screenprint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8mxb.png)

How to tackle this?

Comment: Add "\" at the end of your path variable, then      f=open(path+file, 'r'). If you debug (print) the variable files you will get the "bug"

Comment: Append the file name to glob.glob(path)

Comment: it is a permission error PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: he has to give them read permission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, the initial code with `os.walk` is redundant. You're overriding it with `glob`. Remove it.

Second, you're using [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html#glob.glob) wrong. It accepts an expression to tell it what files you are after.

Try:

```
files=glob.glob(path + os.sep + "*.XFR")
```

This way it will only give you files that end with `"XFR"`. Make sure that case matches.

```
path = r"C:\Users\Ajay\Desktop\abc"
files=glob.glob(path + os.sep + '*.XFR')   
for f in files:     
    with open(f, 'r') as fp:
        print(next(fp, "no data in file: " + f))
```

Comment: Thanks. It helped.

Comment: I think your answer is correct, if you explain why is it giving a permission error which is highly missleading, and elaborate a little we will all be happy